# How to prove a Markov chain is irreducible in general?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

### Consider the following example:

Given a random variable $X_n$ is $Markov(\pi,P)$, where $P$ is irreducible and has an stationary distribution $\pi$.

Then I can show that the *time reversal* of $X_n$, $Y_n=X_{N-n}$ is also a Markov chain. with transition probability $$P(Y_{n+1}=j|Y_{n}=i)=\hat{p}_{ij}=\frac{\pi_jp_{ji}}{\pi_i}$$

However, is the Markov chain for $Y_n$ also irreducible?

### My reasoningss:

From definition, In order to prove irreducibility I need to show that

$$P(Y_n=j | Y_0=i)=\hat{p}^{(n)}_{ij}>0$$ for some $n>0$

The only thing I can think of now is

\begin{align}
P(Y_n=j | Y_0=i)&=\hat{p}_{ik_1}\hat{p}_{k_1k_2}\hat{p}_{k_2k_3}...\hat{p}_{k_{n-1}j}\\& = \frac{\pi_{k_1}p_{k_1i}}{\pi_i}\frac{\pi_{k_2}p_{k_2k_1}}{\pi_{k_1}}\frac{\pi_{k_3}p_{k_3k_2}}{\pi_{k_2}}...\frac{\pi_{j}p_{jk_{n-1}}}{\pi_{k_{n-1}}}\\
&=\frac{\pi_{j}p^{(n)}_{ji}}{\pi_{i}}\end{align}

Since the Markov chain for $X_n$ is irreducible, we know that $p^{(n)}_{ji}>0$ for some $n$. However, I cannot argue $\pi_i$ and $\pi_j$ are always greater than $0$, so we are not 100% sure that $P(Y_n=j | Y_0=i)=\hat{p}^{(n)}_{ij}>0$, since it is possible that $\pi_i=0$ or $\pi_j=0$ for some $i$ and $j$.

So, how do we show that a Markov chain is irreducible in general? What am I missing here?

Comment: "However, I cannot argue $π_i$ and $π_j$ are always greater than $0$" - actually you can, because $\{X_n\}$ is irreducible. If $\pi$ is an stationary distribution, then a state $i$ is transient if and only if $\pi_i=0$. An irreducible Markov chain either has all recurrent states or all transient states.

Comment: Just to double confirm your last statement. Since "if the chain is irreducible, then
either all states are recurrent or all are transient." If all states are transient, then the stationary distribution wouldn't exist. So, it should be an irreducible stationary Markov chain has no transient states, am I right?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: There's so many concepts in Markov chain. If I don't know which concept to use, I can get stuck for hours. However, once someone points out which concept to use, it will suddenly become so obviously. Any tips to be so clear about Markov chain? btw, I like your profile pic, it's a Markov chain, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I got the picture from Wikipedia :)